# can I define multiple LinearLayouts by an array?

Tags: android, arrays, android-linearlayout

I have to inflate a linearLayout containing 3 editTexts into another linearLayout. Can i do it using a linearLayout[] array.

```
public class PurchaseVoucher extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener, OnClickListener{

LinearLayout[] row=new LinearLayout[30];
AutoCompleteTextView[] items=new AutoCompleteTextView[30];
EditText[] quants=new EditText[30];
EditText[] rates=new EditText[30];
TextView[] totals=new TextView[30];
Boolean[] flag=new Boolean[30];
EditText date;
Button save;
LinearLayout container;
int no;
int id;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sale_purchase_vouch);
    no=0;
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
        flag[i]=true;

    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Save);
    save.setText("Confirm Purchase");
    LayoutInflater l=getLayoutInflater();
    container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
    row[no]=(LinearLayout)l.inflate(R.layout.row, container);
    items[no]=(AutoCompleteTextView)row[no].findViewById(R.id.item);
    quants[no]=(EditText)row[no].findViewById(R.id.quant);
    rates[no]=(EditText)row[no].findViewById(R.id.rate);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    quants[no].setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    flag[no]=false;


}


@Override
public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(flag[no+1]==true){

        if(arg1==false){
            no++;
    LayoutInflater g=getLayoutInflater();

    row[no]=(LinearLayout)g.inflate(R.layout.row, container);
    items[no]=(AutoCompleteTextView)row[no].findViewById(R.id.item);
    quants[no]=(EditText)row[no].findViewById(R.id.quant);
    rates[no]=(EditText)row[no].findViewById(R.id.rate);
    Log.d("detection", "Row is "+ no+ arg0.getId());
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("quant", quants[0].getText().toString()+" "+quants[0].getText().toString());
    Log.d("item", items[1].getText().toString()+" "+quants[1].getText().toString());
    Log.d("rate", rates[2].getText().toString()+" "+quants[2].getText().toString());

}
```

}

When I press the button to get the results in the logcat, all the values are equal to the first 3 editTexts ie equal to items[0], quants[0] and rates[0]. Secondly the onFocusChangeListener() only works for the editText present in the first linearLayout that was predefined.

Comment: @codeMagic, No, `no` be `0`. `int`s are auto-instantiated to 0. If it was type `Integer`, then it would be `null`.

Comment: i pulled out some unnecessary code to make it look clean here. But i have taken care of 'no'. It autoincrements whenever required. Howwever the problem comes when I need to get the values from editTexts. That is the reason I asked the question. I thought there was some problem in my approach

Comment: shall i edit my question now to ask the real problem

Comment: @kayveesin yes because this *can* work but if it isn't then we can tell you why unless we know the actual problem

Comment: It is really hard to tell what you are trying to do. Can you explain in more detail what your end goal is? I have not seen any other code that uses this model, so my guess is the best answer would include a different way to meet your end goal.

Comment: I want to add a new row of EditTexts when the user loses focus from the quants[no] editText. Then I want to save the values he entered. It should be like he entered an item name, its quantity and its rate. Then if he wishes to add more items he can use the next line that was newly created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an easier way to do what you are trying would be just to create a new `LinearLayout` and the amount of `EditText`s that you need each time. Then you can also add these values to an array at that time. This way you can have an unlimited amount of rows and I think it may keep your code cleaner. Maybe something like

```
    @Override
public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) 
{ 
    if(flag[no+1]==true){  // not sure if this is needed

    if(arg1==false){
        no++;
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(PurchaseVoucher.this);
        for (int i= 0; i < noOfEditTextNeeded; i++)
        {
             EditText et = new EditText(PurchaseVoucher.this);
             ll.addView(et);
        }
        container.addView(ll);
        llArray.add(ll);  // create a member variable ArrayList-- ArrayList<LinearLayout> = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>()
}
```

I haven't tested this so may need tweaked but to me this would be easier to manage. I created an `ArrayList` to hold the `LinearLayout`s but you could do it for the `EditText`s or whatever you need also.